# Selenium Python Extracting text after .click()

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, element

Good day everyone,

I am having much trouble attempting to click on an element on a website, and after that extracting the text that results from the click. Another consideration is that this code has to be robust enough to loop.

In the modified webpage source code below, id='atelno80112862' is how i identify the element to click. After clicking, the phone number I want "(65) 6890 6333" replaces the text "Call" on the webpage. Afterwards, id='telno80112862' is how I identify the text i want to pull.

```
<div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dgrdCompany_ctl02_idContact">
<a style="display: inline; width: 100px; cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;" id='atelno80112862' onclick="showElement('telno80112862');" title='(65) 6890 6333'>
<img src="/images/call_icon.jpg" />CALL</a>
<a style="display: none; width: 100px;" id='telno80112862' href="tel:(65) 6890 6333">(65) 6890 6333</a>
```

On to my code(i've modified it to zero in on the problem areas):

```
for j in range(2 ,10):
    path5 = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dgrdCompany_ctl0{0}_idContact".format(j)
    path6 = "//a[contains(@id,'atel')]"
    path7 = "//a[@id='telno80112862']"

    try:
        phone = driver.find_element_by_id(path5)
        phone_num = phone.find_element_by_xpath(path6).click()
        phone_info = phone.find_element_by_xpath(path7)
    except:
        print("ERROR: NO PHONE NUMBER")
```

This works partially, and when i loop i get this for each iteration:

(65) 6890 6333
ERROR: NO PHONE NUMBER

The first problem is why am i getting the except output too? The second problem is that i am unable to improve the robustness of path7. It only works if i provide the exact relative xpath. Ive tried using partial xpath "//a[(contains(@id,'telno')]" but doesnt seem to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: The website i am trying to crawl is .    http://www.timesbusinessdirectory.com/category/1000/sme-1000-ranked-companies-2017?classid=sme1000&mid=1913'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code below get all company names and phone numbers on one page.

```
companies = driver.execute_script('return [...document.querySelectorAll("a[id$=Hyperlink4],a[id^=telno]")].map((e,i) => e.innerText.trim())')
print(companies)

for i in range(0, len(companies), 2):
    print('{0} : {1}'.format(companies[i], companies[i+1]))
```

Comment: Hi sers, I tried this but still could not pull the second phone number onwards. However your code solved teh problem of why am i getting the Try: and Except: outputs. I have added in the website in case i am missing out some info that i did not provide!     http://www.timesbusinessdirectory.com/category/1000/sme-1000-ranked-companies-2017?classid=sme1000&mid=1913'

Comment: Hi sers, code works like a charm. Cheers! Is your code able to be modified to crawl for email address too? if yes, I shall dig into it and attempt to do so. Thanks!